# binary search tree - duplicate every item

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, heap-corruption

I'm trying to duplicate given BST

let's say I'm getting this:

```
   2
  / \
 1   3
```

what I'm trying to do is this:

> ```
>       2
>      / \
>     2   3
>    /   /
>   1   3
>  /
> 1
> ```

```
void bTree::mulTree(tNode *tree)
{
    if (!tree)
        return;
    if (tree->left)
        tree->left->left = insert(tree->left->value);
    else
        tree->left = insert(tree->value);

    mulTree(tree->left->left);

    if (tree->value != tree->left->value)
    {
        tree->left->value = tree->value;
        mulTree(tree->right);
    }
}
```

with this code I'm getting the left side like it should be
but if I'm trying to make changes on the right side I'm getting heap error

```
"//mulTree(tree->right);"
```

if I run this I'm getting:
`"HEAP: Free Heap block ... after it was freed"`
but I don't understand where it was already freed... =\

i get the error during this:

```
tree->left = insert(tree->value);
```

insert code:

```
tNode* bTree::insert(int value)
{
    tNode *temp = new tNode();
    temp->value = value;
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: might be relevant in general to your code.. learning and following particular code style *does* help to avoid a lot of errors This one is not the best but still http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml

Comment: I think the problem is probably in a different part of the code. I'm not sure how items are inserted in the tree, nor which part of the code might be free'ing anything. However there is a problem with the duplication function, which is that you overwrite tree->left->left when that node may already exist.

Comment: your code is all wrong. `insert` is just `create_dangling_node`, it does not update any links. and when you reset your links with `tree->left->left = insert(tree->left->value)`, you destroy - cut off - anything there was in a tree below that point. Re-write everything.

Comment: well i'm really got lost with this... if someone can direct me to how it's should be i'll really appreciate it...

Comment: never mind i managed to do it.. tnx =]

Comment: Start with merging bTree and tNode into a single class.. BTW is it by any chance your homework? ;-)